# What are the default subraces in the D&D 3.5 Player's Handbook?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, races, books

I am having difficulty finding information on the default subraces offered in the D&D 3.5 *Player's Handbook*:

- What is the default elf subrace?
- What is the default gnome subrace?
- What is the default dwarf subrace?
- What is the default halfling subrace?

Comment: Default subraces would be a good question. Bundling it with questions about arbitrary subraces makes it unfocused, and full answer would need to include significant portion of "Races" chapters from various rulebooks, including numerous [Dungeons & Dragons campaign settings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_campaign_settings). And, of course, dealing with copyright to images.

Comment: I thought it might be a bit much. I'm dong work on a a ruleset for the module and these questions all bundled together when I was trying to figure out what the races looked liked, and realized I didn't even know what the standard races sub race were.
I'll reduce the question to just asking about the default subrace and ask the appearance question as another question.

Comment: Your related Qs: [What is the description and information for the Deep Orc race in 3.5 D&D?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169330/what-is-the-description-and-information-for-the-deep-orc-race-in-3-5-dd), [Is there an official description of the appearance and culture of tribal orcs?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169329/is-there-an-official-description-of-the-appearance-and-culture-of-tribal-orcs), [Information/physical description of Deep Halflings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169326/i-am-looking-for-information-and-the-physical-description-of-deep-halflings)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Refer to the race's "monster" listing

The "default" subrace for each of the standard races in 3.x is named in the *Monster Manual* entries for the races, where the racial traits from the PHB are reprinted. From the SRD:

- [Elves](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/elf.htm)

  > The above information describes the high elf, the most common variety.
- [Dwarves](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/dwarf.htm)

  > The information above is for hill dwarves, the most common variety.

  (though the mountain dwarf subrace described in the entry has no mechanical differences)
- [Gnomes](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/gnome.htm)

  > The information above is for rock gnomes, the most common variety.
- [Halflings](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/halfling.htm)

  > The information above is for the lightfoot halfling, the most common halfling variety.

These subraces may have different names in specific campaign settings - for instance, in the Forgotten Realms, high elves are known as "Moon" or "silver" elves, and hill/mountain dwarves are "Shield" dwarves (though rock gnomes and lightfoot halflings retain the default name). The appearance of races may also vary between settings; FR's elves, for instance, are much taller than the standard elves described in the PHB, being of comparable height to humans.