# I am looking for information and the physical description of Deep Halflings

Tags: dnd-3.5e, races, racial-traits, halfling

I am looking for the physical description and information on the Deep Halflings race in 3.5 D&D. Can anyone fill me in or direct me to a source?

Comment: Your related Qs: [What is the description and information for the Deep Orc race in 3.5 D&D?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169330/what-is-the-description-and-information-for-the-deep-orc-race-in-3-5-dd), [Is there an official description of the appearance and culture of tribal orcs?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169329/is-there-an-official-description-of-the-appearance-and-culture-of-tribal-orcs), [What are the default subraces in the D&D 3.5 Player's Handbook?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169322/what-are-the-default-subraces-in-the-dd-3-5-players-handbook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Deep Halflings are in the Monster Manual (p. 150)

They lose the bonuses to Climb, Jump and move Silently, but gain bonuses to Appraise and Craft checks with stone or metal.

They also have Stonecunning and Darkvision

> "These halflings are shorter and stockier than the more common lightfeet.
> Deep Halflings are about 2.5 feet tall and weigh between 30 and 35 pounds. Deep halflings speak Dwarven fluently.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information.