# Is there an official description of the appearance and culture of tribal orcs?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, lore, races, orc

I play on a [*Neverwinter Nights*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neverwinter_Nights) [persistent world](https://www.reddit.com/r/neverwinternights/comments/7qnafw/what_is_a_persistent_world/) module that uses the *Dungeons & Dragons 3.5* rules. The module is not using the Forgotten realms setting. I'm editing and updating the module's features into a new document. The module allows players to pick different races. I want to add pictures of the various available races and a short blurb about each race's culture to help players role-play.

However, I'm struggling to locate information on **tribal orcs**. I'd like to have a standard setting brief physical and cultural description of this race that's drawn from official *3.5* material.(Standard means, not using settings like forgotten realms or ebberon)  Is such information available?

Comment: Your related questions: [What is the description and information for the Deep Orc race in 3.5 D&D?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169330/what-is-the-description-and-information-for-the-deep-orc-race-in-3-5-dd), [I am looking for information and the physical description of Deep Halflings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169326/i-am-looking-for-information-and-the-physical-description-of-deep-halflings), [What are the default subraces in the D&D 3.5 Player's Handbook?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169322/what-are-the-default-subraces-in-the-dd-3-5-players-handbook)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108374/discussion-on-question-by-user28536-is-there-an-official-description-of-the-appe).

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone. I considered as many possible sources for the answer as possible, such as alternate names(the way the Orog is also called a deep orc), templates, alternate books. I'm going to leave this as a mystery that I may  serendipitously answer some day.

Comment: And...I found it. I adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that there was an error in the module text.
What the original author of the text had written was tribal orc. What he meant to write was "Gray Orc" from the "Races of Faerun" book.

The original creator of the book responded with...

> My primary resources were the 3.0/3.5 D&D PHB, Monster Manual, and DM
>   Guide. There may have been some other specialized books that I used
>   that I cannot recall. But for the races, I may have also borrowed info
>   from this book:
>
> Races of Faerun (Dungeons & Dragons d20 3.0 Fantasy Roleplaying,
>   Forgotten Realms Setting)

After searching though the book I found the "Gray Orc" with statistical adjustments that matched the statistical adjustments in the NwN module.