# What is the description and information for the Deep Orc race in 3.5 D&D?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, races, orc

I need a physical description and information on the Deep Orc race from 3.5 D&D.
Can someone give me information or direct me to a source that can help me?

I tried searching, but the problem is that it often leads me to the Orog which I am unsure if it's the same as a Deep Orc because the sources lead me to Forgotten Realms pages. Forgotten Realms creatures are not the same. The elven subrace names and even the appearance of the various elf types varies as an example. Even when I search for images I'll get the 5e orog or something from Pathfinder.

I need a simple description and short cultural points on the race. Long detailed information is not required.

Comment: Your related questions: [Is there an official description of the appearance and culture of tribal orcs?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169329/is-there-an-official-description-of-the-appearance-and-culture-of-tribal-orcs), [Information and the physical description of Deep Halflings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169326/i-am-looking-for-information-and-the-physical-description-of-deep-halflings), [What are the default subraces in the D&D 3.5 Player's Handbook?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169322/what-are-the-default-subraces-in-the-dd-3-5-players-handbook)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the only listing of "Deep Orcs" is the Orog from the forgotten realms in 3.5 edition D&D.

They are described as "Physically, an orog looks similar to a large mountain
orc, except that the ears are somewhat larger, and their eyes are huge and pale. They average six and a half feet tall"(71)
They have also "mastered the art of forging armor and weapons from
the strange ores found in the Underdark"(71) and adorn their weapons and armour with spikes.

Source: 
Boyd, Eric. Forbeck, Matt. Jacobs, James. "Races of Faerun" Wizards of the Coast,
March 2003

Comment: I don't know if it's important to your document, but *Races of Faerûn* was released prior to the *3.5* revision (see [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/36990/8610)), making it a *Dungeons & Dragons, Third Edition* source. However, unrevised *Third Edition* material is game-legal in campaigns that use the *3.5* revision, albeit subject to minor adjustments at the DM's discretion (see Why a Revision? on *DMG* (2003) 4). (Further, if it matters, the orog as a monster dates back to at least *AD&D, 2nd Edition* if not far earlier.)

Comment: Hey, @HeyICanChan I'll adjust my answer to say 3.0 edition. Good catch. Since the creator of the module told me that Races of Faerun was one of his sources I'll have to acknowledge that not all the sources he used were standard D&D and some may have been setting specific. I'll leave it at that. The 2nd ed info won't help as far as I know right now.. Thanks for the info!